pymqi ccdt file being ignored?
I'm not really sure what's going on here so hopefully this makes sense to someone. I have a CCDT file provided to me which specifies, in part:
      "clientConnection": {
        "queueManager": "QMGR",
        "connection": [
          {
            "port": 1414,
            "host": "[ip address]"
          }
        ]
      },

And I'm trying to connect with pymqi. I have the MQCHLLIB, MQCHLTAB, MQSSLKEYR, and MQCERTLABL environment variables set.
If I just run this (which has worked with a purely local server), I get an "MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR" response:
qmgr = pymqi.QueueManager(None)
qmgr.connect_with_options("QMGR")

However, if I create a pymqi.CD() structure and then pass it in, with a blank name, it does connect:
cd = pymqi.CD()
cd.ChannelType = pymqi.CMQC.MQCHT_CLNTCONN
cd.TransportType = pymqi.CMQC.MQXPT_TCP
cd.ConnectionName = b"[ip address](1414)"
cd.SSLCipherSpec = b"ANY_TLS13_OR_HIGHER"
cd.ChannelName = b'the channel name'
qmgr.connect_with_options("", cd=cd)

That works fine. Trying just plain old qmgr.connect_with_options("") also doesn't work. So … it seems as if the CCDT file is being somewhat ignored? That is, I have to pass in the data that the CCDT file contains, in the CD structure. Am I missing something obvious here? It seems as if this shouldn't be necessary when the CCDT file exists, and is being read, and from what I can tell this is the way to connect in a way that uses the CCDT data.

What about cd=None?

I think it might mean that it is making a local bindings connection. Try setting env var MQ_CONNECT_TYPE=CLIENT to see if that helps.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/using-ccdt-json-ssltls-ibm-mq-client-using-python-pymqi

That link explains how to get it working. Including setting MQ_CONNECT_TYPE=CLIENT

cd=None also fails and MQ_CONNECT_TYPE doesn't affect things. It turns out that the trick was qmgr.connect_with_options("*QMGR"), with the asterisk. The asterisk's meaning is documented somewhere but I can't really understand why it's necessary in this case. Oh well!

For future readers - could you update your question to show that the queue manager name didn't match the name used to connect. That is not obvious from the question, but it would hugely help future readers if that was the crux of the issue.

When connecting to the queue manager, you need to add an asterisk:
qmgr.connect_with_options("*QMGR")

The asterisk acts as a wildcard and basically says to your application that it shouldn't be too concerned with the actual name of the queue manager it connects to, just as long as it's connection information can be found in that client connection in the CCDT. Without the asterisk, the MQ client will look for an exact match for 'QMGR'. This article explains this concept further.
